# What is the difference between Assignment(=) operator and Equality(==) operator in OPA rule body

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

In OPA documentation https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-testing/ there is a policy definition given like below:

```
allow {
    input.path == ["users"]
    input.method == "POST"
}

allow {
    some profile_id
    input.path = ["users", profile_id]
    input.method == "GET"
    profile_id == input.user_id
}
```

here in first rule it is **input.path == ["users"]** whereas in second rule it is **input.path = ["users", profile_id]**. So can someone help me to point out the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operator in Rego is `:=`, `==` is for comparison, and the `=` operator is for **unification**. There's a section describing the differences [in the docs](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#equality-assignment-comparison-and-unification), but simply put, unification combines assignment *and* comparison, so in your example, given that `input.path` has two elements, the second elements value will be assigned to `profile_id`.

The policy could be written to split comparsion and assignment if you wanted:

```
allow {
    count(input.path) == 2
    input.path[0] == "users"
    profile_id := input.path[1]
    input.method == "GET"
    profile_id == input.user_id
}
```

Which is arguably a bit messier. Unification should however be used sparingly, as in most other cases it is more clear to separate assignment from comparison.

In this particular case, you could even use *only* comparison if you skip the intermediate assignment of `profile_id`:

```
allow {
    input.path == ["users", input.user_id]
    input.method == "GET"
}
```